# OpenCV: How to find the area of a specific contour

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, contour

I am trying to remove noise from a binary image using contour area filtering. I have the following image:

[image]

And I have found the contours using the OpenCV findContours() function. The found contours are outlined in green in the following image.

[image]

Is there any way that I can find the area of a specific contour or do I just have to estimate the areas? E.g. Is it possible to find the area of the contour circled in red?

[image]

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but first of all you need to segregate the contour from the other contours and then you can use `cv2.findContours()` to get the area

Comment: What do you mean exactly by segregating the contour? And how would one be able to segregate it?

Comment: You need to get the bounding box of the desired contour or we can say that you need to get the location of the contour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cv::findContours()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) returns an array of array of the image coordinates corresponding to each contour.

In order to find the area of each contour, you can loop through the number of detected contour and use the function [cv::contourArea()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga2c759ed9f497d4a618048a2f56dc97f1) on each of those array of image coordinates.

In order to find the area of the contour in the red circle, you can introduce a check inside the loop if the median points of selected contour falls inside the circle and find the area only for that contour.

What might also be useful to look into is [cv::minEnclosingCircle()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8ce13c24081bbc7151e9326f412190f1) where you can compute the area of a minimum circle which is fit around the contour points. You can then use the center of this radius and compare it to the location in the image desired by you.

I hope this helps.